# Set Fetched JSON data as state and use it

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm a newbie to React so I'm trying to learn basic concepts.

I'm getting data through an API I hardcoded some data into for learning purposes, with a fetch request like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("myserver.com/api/a/1")
    .then(function(response) {
        response.json()
    })
}
```

and in my constructor I set the state to data: 'false':

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {data: 'false'};
}
```

But from here on I'm lost. I have three different strings in the JSON Object I'm getting through my API but I don't know how to access them. I've tried setting setState in `componentDidMount` but I'm getting loads of error.

How do you do in situations like these? Where should I be setting state, and how do you generally access/iterate over JSON objects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {data: 'false'};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._getData();
    }


    _getData = () => {
        fetch("myserver.com/api/a/1")
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                    return response;
            } else {
                let errorMessage = `${response.status(${response.statusText})`,
                error = new Error(errorMessage);
                throw(error);
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json =>{
           console.log(json);
           this.setState({ data: json.data })
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {
                this.state.data &&
                this.state.data.map( (item, key) =>
                    <div key={key}>
                        {item}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works well! How do I go about displaying this data in my component, ie how do I reach the array of items in the JSON object?

Comment: Eric, modified my answer for simplest case.  `map` is used for array case. {key} is for correct rerendering of item there, item  - for case when you have something simple in your array, will not work if you have another array there

Comment: Thank you! This should work -- good explanation. Although... I'm still getting an error on `.then(json => this.setState({data: json.data}));`, an error of: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Added `return` to  `return response.json()`. Should work now!

Comment: This, sadly, doesn't work for me. It's giving me `Unexpected token` on the `return` keyword. Could this be because of promise error handling?

Comment: I added brackets around it, to `{return response json()}`, but I'm still getting that the state is undefined...

Comment: Hey. Thanks to you and abdul it works, using data => data instead of json => json.data. Would you care to explain the differences? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, I did not know your structure clearly, so this is was only assumption about your data structure, so it would woek if your structure was  for example `{data:{smth: smth}}`

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is to call the JSON.parse() method.

```
    _getData = () => {
                fetch("myserver.com/api/a/1")
                .then(response => {
                   if (response.ok) {
                   return response;
                 } else {
                 let errorMessage = 
                     `${response.status(${response.statusText})`,
                  error = new Error(errorMessage);
                  throw(error);
                 }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json =>{
                   console.log(json);
                   this.setState({ data: JSON.parse(json) })
                });
          }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! In addition to including code, it's usually best to include a short explanation of why/how your solution solves the posted problem. Also I'd suggest you check that this solution actually works because I believe `JSON.parse(json)` will give you a syntax error since `json` is not a string.